# Why does referencing an Enum type property in DTO converter cause all columns to be retrieved (EF Core 7)?

Tags: c#, enums, dto, ef-core-7.0

My apologies for the lengthy intro, but my question is towards the end.

I have implemented a class having a property of type Enum.
I used the following article:

[how-to-use-enums-when-using-entity-framework-core-with-c](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-enums-when-using-entity-framework-core-with-c-bb634692a4b0)

In short, I have a class called `Species` which has a property of type Enum to indicate the common submission type (for that species)

So following the instructions from the article I ended up with the following:

```
public enum CommonSubmissionTypes
{

    [Description("Small Animals")]
    SmallAnimals = 1,
    Farm = 2,
    Equine = 3
}


public partial class Species : EntityBase, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // This is the equivalent of the 'HouseSize' class from the article.
    // This is just here so that a migration will create the underlying table in the database.
    // I've marked it as obsolete, because I don't want this property to be used/referenced in code.
    [Obsolete]
    private CommonSubmissionType CommonSubmissionTypeBC { get; }

    // This relates to the value of the enum
    public int CommonSubmissionTypeId { get; set; }

    // This is the equivalent of the 'HouseSizeEnum' property from the article.
    // I'm just using an extension method to cast the Id to the enum, instead of doing that manually.
    [NotMapped]
    public CommonSubmissionTypes CommonSubmissionType
    {
        get => CommonSubmissionTypeId.ToEnum<CommonSubmissionTypes>();
        set => CommonSubmissionTypeId = (int)value;
    }


}
```

I followed the instructions for creating and seeding the tables using migrations.
That was all fine and I now have the following data:

[image]

[image]

So far so good.
I'm now implementing a list screen where I want to show a list of species.
For this purpose, I have the following DTO

```
public class SpeciesListItemDto : DtoBase
{

    public SpeciesListItemDto(int id, string name, string commonSubmissionType)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        CommonSubmissionType = commonSubmissionType;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CommonSubmissionType { get; set; }
}
```

And I implemented a DTO converter with the following method

```
public static IQueryable<SpeciesListItemDto> ToSpeciesListItemDto(this IQueryable<Species> source)
{
    return source.Select(x => new SpeciesListItemDto(
               x.Id, 
               x.Name, 
               x.CommonSubmissionType.GetDescription()
           ));
}
```

**EDIT (start)**

As requested in the comments, here is some more detail about how the data is retrieved.

The API endpoint calls a service method which does the following:

```
 using (var context = ContextFactory.GetQueryContext())
 {
     var specification = new AllSpeciesSpecification();
     return _queryRepository.FindBySpecification(context, specification).ToSpeciesListItemDto().ToList();
 }
```

The specification defines the where and order by statements

```
public AllSpeciesSpecification()
{
    AddCriteria(x => x.Deleted == false);
    AddOrderBy(x => x.Name);
}
```

The call to `FindBySpecification` returns an `IQueryable<Species>` which takes into account the defined where and order by statements.
Next, the call to `ToSpeciesListItemDto` returns an `IQueryable<SpeciesListItemDto>` which contains the definition of the conversion.
Finally, to materialize the results (i.e. actually query the database) there is a call to .ToList().

**EDIT (end)**

And this works fine:
[image]

**But ...** there's a problem!

If I check in SQL Profiler, I can see that the following SQL statement is being executed:

```
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[Name], [s].[CommonSubmissionTypeId], [s].[CreatedBy], [s].[DateCreated], [s].[DateLastUpdated], [s].[Deleted], [s].[LastUpdatedBy], [s].[Timestamp]
FROM [Species] AS [s]
WHERE [s].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
ORDER BY [s].[Name]
```

**So here's my question!**
Why are all columns being retrieved from the database, even though I'm using a specific `Select` statement on the `IQueryable<Species>`?
How can I ensure that I'm only retrieving the columns `Id`, `Name` and `CommonSubmissionTypeId`?

When I change the DTO so that it has a property of type int and pass in the CommonSubmissionTypeId, then it works as expected (i.e. only 3 columns are retrieved from the database).
It seems that as soon as I reference the non-mapped enum property (deriving from the CommonSubmissionTypeId) it suddenly starts to pull in all columns?

Any ideas?

*Please note that I'm really happen with the rest of the implementation.

I'm not looking for an alternative.

I just want to restrict the number of columns being retrieved from the database.*

Comment: That's not a "DTO Converter", EF has no such concept. Somehow, the query gets enumerated (ie executed) before that call. How and where is `ToSpeciesListItemDto` called? Where's the `Where` call that generated `WHERE [s].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)`  or `ORDER BY [s].[Name]` ?

Comment: In any case this has nothing to do with enum mapping. The problem is in the rest of the implementation. Without that code it's impossible to say where - perhaps there's an `AsEnumerable()` call? Or AutoMapper is used as a DTO converter before `ToSpeciesListItemDto` is called?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in my humble opinion the method `ToSpeciesListItemDto` is indeed a DTO converter as it defines how properties from an EF entity are used to return an instance of a DTO, instead of the EF type itself. But I do apologize if my terminology is incorrect. I do not use AutoMapper. I will add some more details to the post regarding how my DTO converter (sorry, I can't help myself) is called.

Comment: The incorrect terminology is probably the cause of the problem - the query was already executed but you didn't expect this because you're passing an `IQueryable` of the results to the method. `IQueryable` can be used to query *any* container or source, not just EF Core. That `IQueryable` may well come from a `List<>` or the results of an EF query. If you have an `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()`  or an implicit conversion to an `IEnumerable<>`, the query will be executed.

Comment: Is this the *full* SQL query? Or is this part of a more complex nested query? If so, the extra columns won't matter if they aren't used by the rest of the query. The query engine will eliminate unwanted columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in the following line of code `return _queryRepository.FindBySpecification(context, specification).ToSpeciesListItemDto().ToList();`, the SQL query is only executed when we do the final `ToList()`. In other words, no data has been retrieved before the call to `ToSpeciesListItemDto()`. Also, even in that method itself, no actual data is being retrieved yet. Only the final call to 'ToList() will materialize the actual call to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside LINQ to Entities query `Select` you are accessing the unmapped property

```cs
source.Select(x => new SpeciesListItemDto(x.Id, x.Name, x.CommonSubmissionType.GetDescription()))
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ^^^
```

```cs
[NotMapped] // <--
public CommonSubmissionTypes CommonSubmissionType
{
    get => CommonSubmissionTypeId.ToEnum<CommonSubmissionTypes>();
    set => CommonSubmissionTypeId = (int)value;
}
```

and also are calling custom method.

Any of them is enough to make the query non translatable (one of the reasons I don't like unmapped (ignored) properties in entity classes is that you can easily make such mistakes), but especially for the unmapped property EF Core has no other chance than to try evaluate it client side after retrieving all the data (remember, all they see is the declaration of the property, they have no source code to see the implementation).

You are in fact lucky that they try to use client evalution which since EF Core 3.0 is supported in very limited cases (basically only if it is inside the *final* select of the query). If you add any other LINQ operator after the `Select`, you'll receive runtime exception. Which probably you should as well when you access unmapped property, but as I said, you are lucky - for now, since they have habits to fix such things in future releases, so be prepared it to break at any time. After all, in this particular case it is really incorrect usage.

Comment: I'd say this is the opposite of `lucky`. This seems to be the final Select too, so double oops

Comment: @IvanStoev, you're absolutely right. Th penny dropped when you pointed out `all they see is the declaration of the property, they have no source code to see the implementation`. I've been able to make this work by bypassing the non-mapped property. So my DTO converter is now defined as follows: `return source.Select(x =>new SpeciesListItemDto(x.Id, x.Name, x.CommonSubmissionTypeId.ToEnum<CommonSubmissionTypes>().GetDescription()));`. This works as expected now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I can't mark your answer as the right one yet, but will do when I can.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I'll still keep the non-mapped property of type enum as I can use it to evaluate the type in domain logic rather than having to code against an ID. But now I know that when I want to retrieve the name of the enum value I just need to reference the ID property, convert it to the relevant enum type and get the name. Thanks again.